# Can you learn Algebra and Calculus at the same time?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

So I'm trying to catch up to Calc as soon as possible and I have an exam about differential/integral calc in a couple months. I'm not really sharp in Algebra yet, covering Algebra 1 and about to start Algebra 2. Would it be possible to learn algebra 2 and co-learn calc as well? Would like to hear if someone had experience with that.

Thank you.

Comment: Just to name one thing, polynomials, roots and exponents feature pretty heavily in calculus because they behave very nicely and can be used for a big chunk of actual applications. If you're not familiar or comfortable with those, then that will inhibit your understanding of the calculus lessons, simply because when the algebra doesn't flow naturally you will have less brain capacity over to concentrate on the actual calculus stuff.

Comment: Thank you, Arthur, that's really useful. MPW mentioned analytical geometry which I'm a complete 0 at, never studied that before, at the same time it's the first time I've heard about it being necessary for calculus.

Comment: He's quite right that being used to use the coordinate system in an algebraic manner is an important conponent of using calculus in practice. That being said, if you want a taste for what calculus is like, there are resources that don't require much preknowledge, like [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDMsr9K-rj53DwVRMYO3t5Yr).

Answer (score 3):

I would say "No." If you don't already know algebra,  you can't possibly learn calculus. And algebra itself isn't really enough. You really should have exposure to limits and analytic geometry, which typically are introduced in a precalculus course.

So I would buckle down and concentrate on mastering algebra first. Hit calculus after that (or after precalculus following algebra) -- you will understand it more deeply and more quickly if you have the proper tools in your toolkit.

Comment: If you've already seen it but maybe just forgotten because it's been a long time, that's perhaps different. Still, I would say you should master algebra first. Otherwise you will be struggling with tools you should already understand. A shaky understanding of algebra will probably lead to a shaky understanding of calculus. Foundations are everything.